# Airflow - purge all the DAG entries from Web UI for all the deleted DAG files from dags_folder at once

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

After deleting multiple DAG files from the dags folder, need to run `airflow delete_dag dag_id` for each DAG or delete the DAG entries one by one from the web UI.

Instead of doing this, is there a functionality or command to purge the deleted DAGs at one go?

Answer (score 2):

You can always execute queries against your Airflow database directly; we have an Airflow process which cleans up our database periodically by removing entries from `log`, `task_fail`, etc.

As with anything regarding making changes to your database, **make sure you have a backup**.